# Span usage in netstandard 2.1 without dependencies

Tags: c#, .net-standard

[The C# span docs list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1) that spans apply to .NET Core 2.1+ and .NET Standard 2.1. In [Announcing .NET Standard 2.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-standard-2-1/), `Span<T>` is listed as the #1 highlight of the release. 3rd party articles also list the addition of `Span<T>` in .NET Standard 2.1.

I understood these these pieces of evidence to mean that one can use span in the same manner in a netstandard2.1 targeted library as in a netcoreapp2.1 targeted library. I tried this in a library of mine that has zero dependencies where if one targets netcoreapp2.1 then the library's span APIs become available -- for example:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp2.1;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- snip -->

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netcoreapp2.1' Or '$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard2.1'">
    <LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

(The netstandard2.0 used in the snippet is an example of target where the library won't expose `Span` compatible APIs as it would necessitate the `System.Memory` dependency)

But this does not appear to be the case (errors with "type or namespance 'Span<>' could not be found" when targeting netstandard2.1)

It's a goal for this library to have zero dependencies, so I would rather not depend of `System.Memory`.

Is it possible to use `Span` in a netstandard 2.1 library without dependencies in the same manner one can use `Span` in a netcoreapp2.1 without dependencies?

EDIT: The answer is "yes one can use `Span<T>` in netstandard 2.1 without dependencies". I had a bug on my end where I had

```
#if NETCOREAPP2_1
using System;
#endif
```

Instead of

```
#if (NETCOREAPP2_1 || NETSTANDARD2_1)
using System;
#endif
```

Silly mistake. Kinda wish I could delete this question now :D

Comment: You're trying to target netstandard2.0 as well in that project. If your question is just about "can I use Span in netstandard2.1" it would help if you'd provide a [mcve] that *only* targets netstandard2.1.

Comment: But basically, the answer to "Is it possible to use Span in a netstandard 2.1 library without dependencies in the same manner one can use Span in a netcoreapp2.1 without dependencies?" is "Yes" - it's just that's not what your example is trying to do.

Comment: side note: there's also no reason not to use C# 7.2 (or higher) everywhere

Comment: This question pertains to only .netstandard 2.1. The .netstandard 2.0 given in the example is a target of the project that won't include span support because it needs the `System.Memory` dependency. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah the bug was on my end. I had `using System` encapsulated in a `#if NETCOREAPP2_1` whereas I needed `#if (NETCOREAPP2_1 || NETSTANDARD2_1)`

Answer (score 6):

You need System.Memory:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="System.Memory" Version="4.5.4" />
```

You can make this dependency *conditional*, for example to only add it on netstandard2.0:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="System.Memory" Version="4.5.4"
    Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard2.0'"/>
```

which means you can only have the dependency *when it is actually needed*, but: on the TFMs that don't have it inherently, you *will* need the dependency.

Comment: It's slightly unclear whether the OP actually wants to use netstandard2.0 or not. The question text only ever refers to netstandard2.1 (where no dependency is needed) but the example uses netstandard2.0 :(

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. The short answer to "Can I use `Span` in netstandard 2.1 without dependencies" is yes. I had omitted a `using System` under the netstandard 2.1 target

Comment: @NickBabcock if I may offer some guidance, it may be better here to simply drop the netstandard2.0 target; https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/01/net-core-net-5-exodus-of-net-framework.html

Comment: @MarcGravell if I read it correctly, it still seems like for sufficiently self contained libraries (I target more targets than the ones listed above) where there is a minimum amount of logic dedicated to supporting multiple targets that there isn't a significant benefit to rebasing onto netstandard 2.1. Though to your point, even if there is a minimum amount of ifdefs, etc -- one can still make mistakes (as evident here)

Comment: @NickBabcock I would certainly say "add the dependency" before "use #if and have two code paths" - the dependency is *not* expensive here

Comment: @MarcGravell yup agreed. Though System.Memory isn't able to run on netstandard 1.0, afaik. And while netstandard 1.0 is long out of date -- I don't want to go through the ceremony of dropping support quite yet for those yet unknown users who are unfortunately stuck. In my fantasy world, there is a way to know how many users are targeting which framework :D

Comment: @NickBabcock I was advocating dropping netstandard2.0, not netstandard1.0 - *totally* don't try supporting netstandard1.0, indeed